# ChatGPT Api to limit response from provided attributes list

Tags: node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a list of attributes and I want chatgpt api to pick only relevant attributes from the provided list.
For example:
Request Prompt: "Create/Filter five relevant attributes of a **Software Engineer** from provided attributes list"
Response: GPT pick five attributes from provided list of attributes.

I tried following solutions

- Train a custom model. Problem with that is input data can be very random eg: "Software Engineer", "First time home owner" etc. So we can't really have custom model for this.
- Send attributes list with input prompt. This solution is also not feasible and gpt charge on token and attributes list have more than 200 items.
- Maintain a session so just need to send the attributes list first time and use the session to just filter out from the provided list. This sounds most doable but unable to find very much detail to maintain and use the single session of gpt for long time (If possible).